# Threads hold on to memory

Tags: c#, wpf

```
void Method1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var list1 = (List<some objects>)e.Argument;
    var list2 = new List<WaitHandle>();

    foreach (var thing in list1)
    {
        var ws = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        list2.Add(ws);
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new RunDelegate(Method2), thing, ws);
    }

    WaitHandle.WaitAll(list2.ToArray());

    ConvertList1ToPDF(list1);
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------

void Method2(Thing thing, ManualResetEvent handle)
{
    var class = thing;
    Class.RenderImages();
    PDFCount++; 
    UpdateStatusMessage("Do something " + PDFCount + " of " +
        NumberofPfdToCreate.Count() + " compounds");

    handle.Set();
}
```

I have problems with multiple threads that don't release memory. I'm creating PDF charts from data objects.

The arrangement is that I loop through the data objects. For each data object I create a `ManualResetEvent` and add it to `list2`. Then I start a dispatcher with `BeginInvoke`, and pass the `ManualResetEvent` object as a parameter.

Then I have a `WaitHandle.WaitAll(...)` for all `WaitHandle`s.

The problem is that the memory is not being released. It just accumulates until eventually I get an 'out of memory' exception.

I'm not necessarily looking for a solution, just looking if anyone has a good idea what the problem might be.

Running on an WPF 3.5.

Thanks

Comment: can u share the sample code? is it eating up some native memory? [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) should be implemented/followed

Comment: I would love to share some code but, i am not the owner of the code.

Comment: How do mean with IDisposable?

Comment: You can share the code; just anonymise it by removing company details and intellectual property.

Comment: Does `Class.RenderImages();` release all it's memory? Do you save the rendered images in memory? If so, why not create the PDF immediately and release all that memory? Do you have enough memory to create all of those images/PDFs simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) implement IDisposable so you need to dispose of them once you're finished. In this case when Method1 has finished, clear them all up... Add the following to the end of your method

```
void Method1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ...

    foreach(ManualResetEvent mre in list2)
        mre.Dispose();   
}
```

This should allow the unmanaged resources that are being used by the ManualResetEvent to be correctly freed.

You need to check your other methods to ensure that any IDisposable items in there are also freed. Possible culprits in your example are ConvertList1ToPDF and RenderImages.

Comment: Ok, thanks. You guys is a life savers. I have tried with same code before but then i did close instead of Dispose.Now when i try with Dispose he shout out "Cannot access method  'Dispose' here due its proctection level"... any thoughts about that...

Comment: Hmm, in .NET 2.0 it's probably best to cast as an IDisposable (foreach IDisposable mre in list2), IDisposable is implemented explicitly hence it's not visible unless you cast first.

Comment: Could go around it with ((IDisposable)mre).Dispose();.

Comment: Yes, that's the same thing...